# Facebook(Meta) /post/feed Graph API can't retrieve targeting or feed_targeting field in response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, targeting, facebook-public-feed-api

i try to figure out why some of public posts can't display issue. it alaways motions：

This content isn't available right now
When this happens, it's usually because the owner only shared it with a small group of people, changed who can see it or it's been deleted.

then i double check the privacy field in response, that's bellow:

"privacy": {
"allow": "",
"deny": "",
"description": "Public",
"friends": "",
"value": "EVERYONE"
},

then i search FAQ in facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/support/faq/
found a question just like what i meet, 'Page Post is targeted or is gated to be visible only to a specific audience' so i add 2 additional value(targeting,feed_targeting) in 'fields' parameter in '/post/feed' API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v17.0/page/feed

but it doesn't work, the response json body still can't retrieve those 2 addition field(targeting,feed_targeting).
so i stuck hear, anyone can help?

#facebook #meta #

get targeting,feed_targeting fields in reponse json body for listing public post api:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v17.0/page/feed

Comment: If you are not getting those fields in the response, then likely they weren't set to any value at all.